# Python 2.7 bz2.decompress issue (cannot read the whole file)

Tags: python, compression, bz2

I have some issues when I decompress bz2 files in python.
I have the same issue in Windows 7 and red hat. Both are running Python 2.7 Anaconda distributions.

```
python -V
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)


C:\Users\XXXXX>python -V
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

When I read a bz2 file, I only get the first 900kBytes of the files:

```
                    sftp = client.open_sftp()
                    with sftp.file(path, 'rb') as f:
                        if ".bz2" in path:
                            u = f.read()
                    client.close()


                    client.open_sftp()
                    s = bz2.decompress(u).split("\n")
                    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('bzcat %s' % path)
                    s2 = stdout.readlines()
                    client.close()
```

bz2.decompress only gives me the first 900000 bytes. **s2** is almost always bigger than **s**.

This is true no matter what envrionment I choose Read hat or Windows.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: you could have a try with a newest python like 3.6

Comment: Thanks, it is a massive project,  I cannot change the python version right now.

Comment: have you checked the data? is it correct at least? (the beginning of the data, I mean)

Comment: yes, a bzcat query works perfectly fine ...

Comment: you _could_ try with a newest version in a small example, like the one you're showing. Else a workaround will be to use `bzcat` like you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't want to install 3.6 now. I am not looking for another workaround than the one I already set. Though, a built-in function in Python 2.7, should never fail. I think this is serious bug (if my usage is right obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check if your bzip-file is a multi-stream file, as python2's bz2 module does not support decoding multi-stream bzip files (it will decode the first stream only, truncating all other streams).

See also:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File